# Perl: match regex from the file

Tags: regex, perl

I have a tab-delimited file that contains information about itemsets. Each itemset consists of one to three items:

```
MTMR14_Q1   NOTCH1_Q3   PRKCD_Q1        
MTMR14_Q1   NOTCH1_Q3   TFRC_Q3     
MTMR14_Q1   NOTCH1_Q3           
MTMR14_Q1           
MTMR14_Q1   PASD1_Q3
```

My goal is to retrieve itemsets with three items only:

```
MTMR14_Q1   NOTCH1_Q3   PRKCD_Q1        
MTMR14_Q1   NOTCH1_Q3   TFRC_Q3
```

I have wrote the following code, but it does not retrieve any itemsets:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $input = shift @ARGV or die $!; 

open (FILE, "$input") or die $!;

while (<FILE>) {
    my $seq = $_;
    chomp $seq;
        
    if ($seq =~ /[A-Z]\t[A-Z]\t[A-Z]/) {  
        #using the binding operator to match a string to a regular expression
    
        print $seq . "\n";
    }
}

close FILE;
```

Could you, please, pinpoint my error?

Comment: You are only matching single uppercase characters without repetition, space or a `_`

Comment: Match one or more chars, `/^[^\t]+\t[^\t]+\t[^\t]+$/`

Comment: One liners: `awk 'NF == 3' input.tsv` or `perl -lane 'print if @F == 3' input.tsv`

Comment: @Shawn Those split on whitespace, not on tabs. I don't know how to adjust the awk one, but the Perl one can be fixed by adding `-F'\t'`

Comment: @ikegami I left that out because it makes no difference with OP's sample data. (And guess what language/program perl lifted `-F` from?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[A-Z]` matches a single letter.

---

Skip lines that don't contain exactly 3 fields:

```perl
next if $seq !~ /^ [^\t]* \t [^\t]* \t [^\t]* \z/x;
```

`[^\t]*` matches any number of non-tab characters.

---

Skip lines that don't contain exactly 3 non-empty fields:

```perl
next if $seq !~ /^ [^\t]+ \t [^\t]+ \t [^\t]+ \z/x;
```

`[^\t]+` matches any one-or-more non-tab characters.

---

Presumably, you'll be following up by parsing the lines to get the three fields. If so, you could parse first and check after, like the following does:

```perl
my @fields = split /\t/, $seq, -1;

next if @fields != 3;                    # Require exactly 3 fields.

next if ( grep length, @fields ) != 3;   # Requite exactly 3 non-empty fields.
```